# How can I tell where a snapshot version is being specified for a particular artifact?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I'm using Maven 3.5.2 and Java 8.

I'm working on a project, where I'm now getting the following on a desktop build of the project:

> Could not find artifact ::jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT in ...

If I look in our intranet Nexus repo, I see version "2.2.0" of this artifact, but not 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.  Our snapshot artifacts expire after a period, which causes problems like this from time to time.  The build on our CI server is not failing, because the local maven repo on the CI server doesn't get cleared before every build (I've mentioned that this should happen), so that version of that artifact is in that local maven repo.  In fact, I had that version of this artifact in my desktop local maven repo earlier this morning, but I unfortunately deleted it while trying to debug this error that was originally reported to me by another user.

In our application pom, we're not specifying this artifact at all. It's specified in the parent pom.  In that parent pom, the version is not specified.

What I'd like to figure out is WHERE this version of "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT" for this artifact is being specified.  I thought that perhaps "dependency:tree" would do this, but unfortunately this plugin won't print the tree if it can't resolve all the dependencies, which is what happens in this case.

I can view the parent pom in Eclipse, and in the "Dependencies" tab, it shows this artifact with "(managed:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT)". That parent pom has no parent.

So if this version is "managed", how can I tell what is managing it?  Can I use either mvn at the command line or the Nexus gui to tell me what is specifying this version?

**Update**:

I already knew that the "dependencyManagement" section is where versions are typically specified for "other poms" to use, but I'd already looked for this version spec in the entire pom (both app and parent), and didn't find it.

The first answer here made me realize that I needed to look for BOM artifacts (bill of materials), which are only used to specify versions for groups of artifacts.

When I finally looked at the dependencyManagement section of the parent pom, I saw it referenced a BOM artifact, and when I visited that artifact, I found the version that was being specified.

so NOW, what I'd like to know is whether there's anything in maven (or in eclipse m2e) that would TELL ME what I had to dig to find out.  I have a feeling the answer is no.

Comment: Usually if a release of an artifact is released the according SNAPSHOT version is deleted cause it does not make sense anymore to use the SNAPSHOT version. So for example using a `2.2.0-SNAPSHOT` should be changed to `2.2.0` which is the release version. There is the question: Why are you using SNAPSHOT versions at all and not rely only on released versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of a "managed" artifact is determined by the `<dependencyManagement>`. The dependencyManagement may be in your POM or the parent POM. Furthermore, it may contain elements with `<scope>import</scope>`, which means that further entries are imported from the specified POM.

Comment: I pretty much already knew this, and when I first read this, I assumed it wouldn't help, because I knew I had already searched the entire pom and parent pom for "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT", and the string didn't even occur, but then I looked closer at the dependencyManagement section in the parent pom, and it had two BOM artifacts.  When I opened up the first one, I saw it was specifying this version for this artifact.  Now, I'm going to add an update to the question.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Actually, I cannot give you a satisfactory answer to your second question. What we do: First of all, we keep one SNAPSHOT of each version in the repository, so that builds won't break (esp. `dependency:tree`). Secondly, we try to have a clear structure in the BOMs so that it is easy to find out where an artifact comes from.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I just noticed that if you hover over a dependency in Eclipse, m2e will show you where the version is managed. This might help.

Comment: Hot dang!  That'll do it.